# Including a formatted iterable as part of a larger formatted string

Tags: python, python-3.x

In writing a class recently, I initially included a `__repr__` method along the following lines:

```
return "{}({!r}, {!r}, {!r})".format(
                self.__class__.__name__,
                self.arg1,
                self.arg2,
                self.arg3)
```

Repeating the '{!r}' snippet like that feels wrong and would be tedious to maintain if I ever add any more arguments to this class. However, the more robust alternatives that occurred to me aren't going to win any prizes for elegance either.

Building the format string programmatically:

```
fmt = "{}(%s)" % ", ".join(["{!r}"]*3)
return fmt.format(self.__class__.__name__,
                  self.arg1,
                  self.arg2,
                  self.arg3)
```

Formatting the arguments separately with `str.join`:

```
args = ", ".join(map(repr, [self.arg1, self.arg2, self.arg3]))
return "{}({})".format(self.__class__.__name__, args)
```

I've currently implemented the class using the last example, but I'm interested in suggestions for alternative approaches (since I'm not particularly happy with any of the above options).

**Update:**
Inspired by Ned's answer, I've now added the following utility function to a helper module:

```
def format_iter(iterable, fmt='{!r}', sep=', '):
    return sep.join(fmt.format(x) for x in iterable)

>>> format_iter(range(10))
'0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9'
>>> format_iter(range(10), sep='|')
'0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9'
>>> format_iter(range(10), fmt='{:04b}', sep='|')
'0000|0001|0010|0011|0100|0101|0110|0111|1000|1001'
>>> format_iter(range(10), fmt='{0.real}+{0.imag}j')
'0+0j, 1+0j, 2+0j, 3+0j, 4+0j, 5+0j, 6+0j, 7+0j, 8+0j, 9+0j'
```

**Update2:**
I ended up adding a second utility function, almost identical to the one in agf's answer:

```
def call_repr(name, *args):
    return "{}({})".format(name, format_iter(args))
```

So the originally offending `__repr__` function now looks like:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return call_repr(self.__class__.__name__,
                     self.arg1,
                     self.arg2)
```

(Yes, one of the original constructor arguments went away earlier today.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this is a pattern you're going to repeat, I'd probably use:

```
# This is a static method or module-level function
def argrepr(name, *args):
    return '{}({})'.format(name, ', '.join(repr(arg) for arg in args))

def __repr__(self):
    return argrepr(self.__name__, self.arg1, self.arg2, self.arg3)
```

or

```
# This is a static method or module-level function
def argrepr(*args):
    return '(' + ', '.join(repr(arg) for arg in args) + ')'

def __repr__(self):
    return repr(self.__name__) + argrepr(self.arg1, self.arg2, self.arg3)
```

Comment: As it turned out, I ended up doing this, only with a ``format_iter(args)`` call in place of the inline invocation of ``str.join``

Answer (score 8):

My inclination would be, if you don't like the code, hide it in a function:

```
def repr_all(*args):
    return ", ".join(repr(a) for a in args)


def __repr__(self):
    args = repr_all(self.arg1, self.arg2, self.arg3)
    return "{}({})".format(self.__class__.__name__, args)
```

Comment: Accepted, since this was the direct inspiration for what I ended up doing (see update)

Comment: Well, it was the accepted answer for a while, until my solution evolved to look more like the suggestion from agf :)

Answer (score 0):

I might do it like:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "{0}({1})".format(
        type(self).__name__,
        ", ".join(repr(arg) for arg in (self.arg1, self.arg2, self.arg3)))
```

or:

```
_init_getter = operator.attrgetter('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3')
def __repr__(self):
    return "{0}({1})".format(
        type(self).__name__,
        ", ".join(repr(arg) for arg in self._init_getter(self)))
```